# Should I use gnu parallel mode function inside openMP parallel region(for-loop, tasks)

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I have a program accelerated by `openMP`, inside the parallel region, functions like `std::nth_element`, `std::sort`, `std::partition` are called. actually, these functions are used to process each openmp-thread's corresponding part of an array.

recently, I found g++ had implemented parallel version of above functions, So I wonder should I use function like `__gnu_parallel::nth_element` inside `#pragma omp task` or `#pragma omp for` region? if I used the parallel mode, would the total threads exceed the limit set by `omp_set_num_threads()` and lead to worse speedup?

Answer (score 0):

Trivial (and best) answer: Benchmark and post your findings.

Less definitive: In my experience, the parallel versions of **most** algorithms are less efficient than the comparable serial ones, instead relying on multiple parallel processors to compensate in wall time. Regarding the number of threads, I don't think that OMP will spawn new threads if at the limit. I do remember that embedded `#pragma omp for` regions don't actually result in each of the outer threads spawning more "inner threads" without a specific flag (which I don't remember off the top of my head).